# Pandas replace column value with Last available value

Tags: python, pandas, date, conditional-statements, vectorization

For sample data frame that can be derived using code below, I want to update the column `Offset_Date` such that for any date in column `Offset_Date` that is not within column `Date` I want to replace that date in `Offset_Date` with last available value in column `Date`.

```
data = {"date": ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05',
                 '2021-01-07', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10', '2021-01-11'],

        "offset_date": ['2021-01-02', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05',
                        '2021-01-06', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-10',
                        '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12']}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
test_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['date'])
test_df['offset_date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['offset_date'])
```

To explain further in 1st row of above data frame date `2021-01-02` is not within column `date` so I want to replace that value with last available value in column `date` i.e.  `2021-01-01`.

I want to perform a vectorized approach so I tried the following, which lead to incorrect results.

```
test_df['offset_date_upd'] = np.where(test_df['offset_date'] in test_df['date'].values,
                                      test_df['offset_date'], 
                                      test_df[test_df['date'] <= test_df['offset_date']].values.max())
```

How can I get the below desired output using a vectorized approach?

**Desired Output**

```
+------------+-------------+
|    Date    | Offset_Date |
+------------+-------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01  |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01  |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-05-01  |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-01  |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-01  |
| 2021-09-01 | 2021-10-01  |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-01  |
| 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-01  |
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of Pandas' [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=merge_asof) function.
We have to be specific about which columns are going where.  This will work as a left join and in this case, we want `'offset_date'` to represent the "left".  Then, for each value in `'offset_date'`, we look for the greatest value in `'date'` that does not exceed that value in `'offset_date'`.

The one gotcha in this approach is that both columns need to be sorted.  If this is an issue with the real data, let me know and I'll add a section at the bottom that deals with this.

```
new_offset_date = pd.merge_asof(
    test_df[['offset_date']],  # limit `test_df` to just the column I need for the merge
    test_df[['date']],         # limit `test_df` to just the other column I need
    left_on=['offset_date'],   # name the columns since they have different names
    right_on=['date']          # name the other column as well
)['date']
```

Now the new dates are in a `pandas.Series`, we can see it if we use the `assign` method which **DOES NOT** overwrite your dataframe and you'll need to use `test_df = test_df.assign(offset_date=new_offset_date)` to actually persist the new dates in the dataframe.

```
test_df.assign(offset_date=new_offset_date)

        date offset_date
0 2021-01-01  2021-01-01
1 2021-01-03  2021-01-04
2 2021-01-04  2021-01-05
3 2021-01-05  2021-01-05
4 2021-01-07  2021-01-07
5 2021-01-09  2021-01-10
6 2021-01-10  2021-01-11
7 2021-01-11  2021-01-11
```

Comment: This solution is the one that actually do for sure this part of the code in the question `test_df[test_df['date'] <= test_df['offset_date']].values.max()`. the other 2 answers so far, while good in the case both dates and offset_dates are ordered and not overlapping, would failed if the first offset_date is '2021-01-08' for example. not sure if this case is possible in the real data

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use `isin`, `mask`, and `fillna`:

```
test_df['offset_date'] = (test_df['offset_date']
                          .where(test_df['offset_date'].isin(test_df['date']),
                                 test_df['date'])
                         )
```

output:

```
        date offset_date
0 2021-01-01  2021-01-01
1 2021-01-03  2021-01-04
2 2021-01-04  2021-01-05
3 2021-01-05  2021-01-05
4 2021-01-07  2021-01-07
5 2021-01-09  2021-01-10
6 2021-01-10  2021-01-11
7 2021-01-11  2021-01-11
```

Answer (score 2):

The bellow approach should works for your case

```py
test_df["offset_date"] = np.where(
    test_df.offset_date.isin(test_df.date),
    test_df.offset_date,
    test_df.date
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).